# c# wpf read only folder

Tags: c#, wpf, readonly

I am creating a new folder in documents and after that I want to write a file to it. The problem is, is that the folder I create is 'read only'. So I can't add a file to it. I can't fix it.

What I have now:

```
string target_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "data");
Directory.CreateDirectory(target_path);
var di = new DirectoryInfo(target_path);
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

I also made my program startup as administrator but that doesn't make any difference.

### Edit

When trying to store a file inside the folder I get the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "xxxx"' is denied.'

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you think the folder is “'read only”? Did you try creating a file in it? Are you looking at the Folder Attributes in Windows Explorer? Does the checkbox have a square in it? [That doesn't mean you can't add things to the folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-fo)!

Comment: What folder are you trying to change permissions on?

Comment: i want to create a folder inside my documents and afterwards i want to store a file inside that folder. but i get the error:  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "xxxx"' is denied.'

Comment: The code you posted does not “store a file inside that folder” and when I tried doing that running as a Standard user it worked fine. Folders you create in your Documents folder are not “read-only“ and you do not have to change folder attributes to store a file there. You also need to tell us the actual error message, not just a few words you picked out of the message.

Comment: i am using CSMatio. The store function is as follows: MatFileWriter mfw = new MatFileWriter(target_path, mlList, false); Here i get the error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "xxxx"' is denied. When i make the folder myself and run this function it is working, so that is really strange

Answer (score 0):

try explicitly set permissions.

```
string target_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "data");
DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Users",FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(target_path, securityRules);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! i still get this error message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "xxxx"' is denied.'